# How can I append my Where clause in this scope statement?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, syntax, scope

I have this in my `Section` model.

```
scope :active, {
  select: 'sections.*, COUNT(quizzes.id) as quiz_count',
  joins: 'LEFT JOIN quizzes ON quizzes.section_id = sections.id',
  group: 'sections.id',
  having: 'quiz_count > 0',
  where: 'sections.is_test = true'
}
```

Which works perfectly if I do not include that `where` key.

But how can one append this `where` clause within the statement to make it syntactically correct?

Comment: Have you tried putting it after the 'joins:' part?

Comment: No matter where I put it, it returns `ArgumentError: Unknown key: where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you please post the relationships of your models in the scope?

As far as I can guess, you can try like this

```
scope :active, {
  select: 'sections.*, COUNT(quizzes.id) as quiz_count where sections.is_test=true',
  joins: 'LEFT JOIN quizzes ON quizzes.section_id = sections.id',
  group: 'sections.id'
  having: 'quiz_count > 0'
}
```

**update**
Maybe you can use merge scope, like

```
scope :test, {where is_test: true},
```

then

```
Section.test.active.
```

I looked through the upper code, in this condition, we don't have to use the upper sql, we can just use

```
counter_cache: true
```

and the scope could be

```
scope :active,{where("quiz_count>?",0)}
```

reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

Comment: Ah for sure I thought that was going to work. Returns `SQLite3::SQLException: near "FROM": syntax error: SELECT sections.*, COUNT(quizzes.id) as quiz_count where sections.is_test=true FROM "sections" LEFT JOIN quizzes ON quizzes.section_id = sections.id GROUP BY sections.id HAVING quiz_count > 0`

Comment: OK, let me think about it.

Comment: Yah so I went with the two scope idea you brought up. That works. Thanks!